# Time: Determining in system shows 12 or 24 hours

Tags: java, android, date, time, android-date

I am saving a Date to SharedPreferences so it  needs to be saved as a string. That's fine. However, I need to display this date (more specifically the time) at a later point.

I would like the time to be displayed in 12 hour or 24 inline with the system displayed preference. The problem is that I can't find a method of doing this. There are some answers floating around to check date patterns for "am" or "pm" or even "h". Another answer what to use: `DateFormat.is24Hour(). But this does not seem to exist anymore (I can't find out to get that method anywhere!)

What's the best method to solve this?

Comment: [`is24HourFormat()` still exists](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#is24HourFormat(android.content.Context)).

Comment: @A--C When I try `DateFormat.is24HourFormat()`, it says the method is undefined.

Comment: Make sure that you're importing `android.text.format.DateFormat` and that you are supplying a `Context` as an argument.

Comment: @A--C Thanks! I had imported the wrong `DateFormat`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two classes named `DateFormat`:

- `java.text.DateFormat`
- `android.text.format.DateFormat`

The method `is24HourFormat()` is found only in `android.text.format.DateFormat` class. You only have to pay attention importing the correct class.